# Include aura component (paginator) in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, pagination

I have a visualforce page and aura component. I need to include this component in a visualforce page. How can I do this? Thanks for help!

Visualforce page:
[image]

I took the lightning component here:
https://sfdcfacts.com/lightning/lightning-pagination-with-page-number-navigation-using-client-side-controller/
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) with the techniques outlined in the documentation.

First, you create a dependency app (Lightning App):

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="c:LightningPaginationClientSide"/>
</aura:application>
```

Then include this code in your Visualforce:

```
<apex:includeLightning/>
<div id="lightning" />
```

And then have this script block:

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:paginationClientSideDependencyApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:LightningPaginationClientSide",
          {  }, // Pass any properties you need here
          "lightning", // "id" of the container div to host the component
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          }
      );
    });
</script>
```